# Calling LexV2 from a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-lex

I currently have a lambda function that is triggered using an api-gateway and I wish to call or invoke LexV2 from within this lambda function. Any idea how can I do such a thing? I can't find any examples of such a scenario?

I need this as I want to use lex on platforms other than (Facebook messanger, Twillio SMS & Slack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further digging I was able to find that the goal was achievable by using [Lex Runtime service client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lex-runtime-v2/index.html) which offers sending messages to lambda.

Note: Be sure that you use the LexV2 libraries to avoid future problems